# Problems replacing head of a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

Writing a function to do a head insert on a linked-list. It's half working as in it's inserting the object into head and reattaching the list but I'm losing my original head node in the list somehow.

If list is [green, red, blue] and I try to insert yellow, it will work but the new list will be [yellow, red, blue].

Node class is:

```
template<class T>
class Node
{
public:
    Node(T theData, Node<T>* theLink) : data(theData), link(theLink){}
    Node<T>* getLink( ) const { return link; }

    const T& getData( ) const { return data; }

    void setData(const T& theData) { data = theData; }
    void setLink(Node<T>* pointer) { link = pointer; }

private:
    T data;
    Node<T> *link;
};
```

List is stored into a queue, so the head insert is a method of that class. Queue has private variables front and back that point to the corresponding positions of the list.

```
template<class T>
void Queue<T>::headInsert(T& theData)
{
   Node<T> *temp;
   temp = front->getLink();
   front->setLink(new Node<T>(theData, temp->getLink() ));
   front = front->getLink();
}
```

Comment: Why bother with getters and setters? Just make them public members.

Comment: You might want to look at working [code for a linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3479326/179910).

Comment: @Pubby: In general I would agree for such a trivial structure. It hurts nothing to have the getter and setters though. But it *does* add the flexibility of adding validation logic. You can add code in the setter to detect if a cycle would occur. This would be useful in debug builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your `setLink` call:

```
template<class T>
void Queue<T>::headInsert(T& theData)
{
   Node<T> *temp;
   temp = front->getLink();
   front->setLink(new Node<T>(theData, temp->getLink() )); // Right here
   front = front->getLink();
}
```

You actually have a number of problems. First off, let's suppose we have the following test list:

`front = Red -> Green -> Blue -> NULL`

The call `temp = front->getLink()` yields the following output:

`temp = Green -> Blue -> NULL`.

The `new Node<T>(theData, temp->getLink())` call, where `theData = Yellow`, then yields:

`new Node<T>(theData, temp->getLink())` = `Yellow -> Blue -> NULL`.

Calling `front->setLink(new(...)` then gives you:

`front = Red -> Yellow -> Blue -> NULL`

Lastly, `front = front->getLink()`:

`front = Yellow -> Blue -> NULL`.

This is not what you want. You simply want to take `yellow` and pop it on the front of the list:

```
template<class T>
void Queue<T>::headInsert(T& theData)
{
   front = new Node<T>(theData, front);
}
```

No need to modify internal pointers. Just point front to be the new node containing your data, with it's next pointer pointing to the old data.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: @frankV: See my edit. I neglected to see the error on the line right after the one I suggested replacing.

Comment: should that be `Node<T> *next...`?

Comment: It's still doing the same thing.

Comment: Why not just `front = new Node<T>(theData, front->getLink())`

Comment: @CrazyEddie: I just changed it. The `getLink()` call is wrong actually.

Comment: @CrazyEddie because that drops whatever was previously stored in front. Trying to "append" an object to the front of the list, and keep the rest of the list intact.

Comment: @frankV: It's useful to work out your algorithms on a small test case. I've added the execution of your diagram to my answer to explain why the old code was wrong.